# RuntimeError: Shape of a tensor not matching with image masking

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensor

Im  trying to change the code from ( https://github.com/Microsoft/singleshotpose )
Its a CNN which is using 9 keypoints, 8 from the bounding box and a centroid to train the network on finding those points. I want to try and train the image on only 4 keypoints instead of the 9 from the original code. Im trying to change the code step by step but now im having an error i just cant solve.

I will give a Code snippet of the lossfunction:

```
def build_targets(pred_corners, target, num_keypoints, num_anchors, num_classes, nH, nW, noobject_scale, object_scale, sil_thresh, seen):
    nB = target.size(0)
    nA = num_anchors
    nC = num_classes
    conf_mask   = torch.ones(nB, nA, nH, nW) * noobject_scale
    coord_mask  = torch.zeros(nB, nA, nH, nW)
    cls_mask    = torch.zeros(nB, nA, nH, nW)
    txs = list()
    tys = list()
    for i in range(num_keypoints):
        txs.append(torch.zeros(nB, nA, nH, nW))
        tys.append(torch.zeros(nB, nA, nH, nW)) 
    tconf = torch.zeros(nB, nA, nH, nW)
    tcls  = torch.zeros(nB, nA, nH, nW) 

    num_labels = 2 * num_keypoints + 3 # +2 for width, height and +1 for class within label files
    nAnchors = nA*nH*nW
    nPixels  = nH*nW
    for b in range(nB):
        cur_pred_corners = pred_corners[b*nAnchors:(b+1)*nAnchors].t()
        cur_confs = torch.zeros(nAnchors)
        for t in range(50):
            if target[b][t*num_labels+1] == 0:
                break
            g = list()
            for i in range(num_keypoints):
                g.append(target[b][t*num_labels+2*i+1])
                g.append(target[b][t*num_labels+2*i+2])

            cur_gt_corners = torch.FloatTensor(g).repeat(nAnchors,1).t() # 16 x nAnchors
            cur_confs  = torch.max(cur_confs, corner_confidences(cur_pred_corners, cur_gt_corners)).view_as(conf_mask[b]) # some irrelevant areas are filtered, in the same grid multiple anchor boxes might exceed the threshold

        conf_mask[b][cur_confs>sil_thresh] = 0
```

the error i get is the following:

```
File "c:\python_work\singleshotpose\region_loss2.py", line 56, in build_targets
cur_confs  = torch.max(cur_confs, corner_confidences(cur_pred_corners, cur_gt_corners)).view_as(conf_mask[b]) # some irrelevant areas are filtered, in the same grid multiple anchor boxes might exceed the threshold
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (13) must match the size of tensor b (169) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

It tells me the tensor dont have the same size. As far as I understand im using the corner_confidences function to find the distance betweend the predicted and ground truth corners. Afterwards it returns the max between the initialised confidences and those new confidences. When .view_as is left out the code works for the first for iteration and stops on the second when comparing with the sil_thresh.

These are the results when i print the .size() of gt_corners, pr_corners and conf_mask
additionaly i ad the size of the other variables for better unterstanding:

```
nB = 8, nA = 1, nC = 1, nH = 13, nW = 13, num_keypoints = 4
cur_pred_corners=torch.Size([8, 169])
cur_gt_corners=torch.Size([8, 169])
conf_mask=torch.Size([8, 1, 13, 13])
```

Also I'll add the corners_confidences function for maybe more clarity

```
def corner_confidences(gt_corners, pr_corners, th=80, sharpness=2, im_width=640, im_height=480):
    ''' gt_corners: Ground-truth 2D projections of the 3D bounding box corners, shape: (16 x nA), type: torch.FloatTensor
        pr_corners: Prediction for the 2D projections of the 3D bounding box corners, shape: (16 x nA), type: torch.FloatTensor
        th        : distance threshold, type: int
        sharpness : sharpness of the exponential that assigns a confidence value to the distance
        -----------
        return    : a torch.FloatTensor of shape (nA,) with 9 confidence values 
    '''
    print(f"gt_corners: {gt_corners.size()}")
    print(f"pr_corners: {pr_corners.size()}")
    shape = gt_corners.size()
    torch.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
    print(f"test: {shape}")
    nA = shape[1]  
    dist = gt_corners - pr_corners
    num_el = dist.numel()
    num_keypoints = num_el//(nA*2)
    dist = dist.t().contiguous().view(nA, num_keypoints, 2)
    dist[:, :, 0] = dist[:, :, 0] * im_width
    dist[:, :, 1] = dist[:, :, 1] * im_height

    eps = 1e-5
    distthresh = torch.FloatTensor([th]).repeat(nA, num_keypoints) 
    dist = torch.sqrt(torch.sum((dist)**2, dim=2)).squeeze() # nA x 9
    mask = (dist < distthresh).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    conf = torch.exp(sharpness*(1 - dist/distthresh))-1  # mask * (torch.exp(math.log(2) * (1.0 - dist/rrt)) - 1)
    conf0 = torch.exp(sharpness*(1 - torch.zeros(conf.size(0),1))) - 1
    conf = conf / conf0.repeat(1, num_keypoints)
    # conf = 1 - dist/distthresh
    conf = mask * conf  # nA x 9
    mean_conf = torch.mean(conf, dim=1)
    return mean_conf
```

Im having this error now for a couple of days and just cant find a solution, hopefuly somebody can help me!
Thank u all

Comment: probably you need `conf_mask.flatten(start_dim=-2)`

Comment: Added before `cur_confs  = torch.max(cur_confs, corner_confidences(cur_pred_corners, cur_gt_corners)).view_as(conf_mask[b])`
but unfortunaly ill get the same error message

Comment: The same error cannot be. `conf_mask = conf_mask.flatten(start_dim=-2)` changes the shape of the tensor, either the code becomes correct or the error message is different

Comment: you are right it worked,  but the new size is `conf_mask=torch.Size([1352])`

Comment: I changed the shape with `conf_mask = conf_mask.view(8, -1)` and it works. but I get another error message later on having the wrong size, because the tensor changed. But I appreciate your help at least I got some steps forward (:

Comment: You can save the previous size, do the operation and then put it back to the previous size with .reshape